# How to change the Brush color from a Pen in a DrawingGroup.Children tag

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, blend

I'm trying to change the property Brush from the next piece of code from another control, but don't know how to reach to this property.

This drawing brush is defined as an Application.Resource en App.XAML

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="Disp_Origin" Stretch="Uniform">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 720.099,497.862C 778.822,493.976 837.662,492.02 896.514,492.02">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen Thickness="1.33333" MiterLimit="2.75" Brush="#FFA5AEB7"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    </GeometryDrawing>...
```

I need to reach the pen brush property when another control gets focused or hovered.

I don't know if this is possible

Comment: Do you want to modify the resource `Disp_Origin` (you can't modify it), or just change the color of the control (with this resource is setted)?

Comment: Just modify the property Brush of the tag Pen, inside of Disp_Origin

Comment: You can add another resource `Disp_Origin_with_another_brush`, and change whole `DrawingBrush` resoure when the control gets focused or hovered (using `Trigger` for example). I think it's simpliest solution.

Comment: The trick is that there are various GeometryDrawing tags inside the DrawingBrush, and I want change one or another depending the control I was interacting.

Here is a pic of example [link](http://i1076.photobucket.com/albums/w451/Guille_Marquez/Example.png)

When mouse goes over the differents radio buttons, the linked GeometryDrawing must change color.

Comment: There are 15 variations and repeat 15 times the same resource, just modifying one color, I think it's not the smart way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I've found how to do this. But it requires code behind. Most important is `Clone()` method it allows to change control's resource and you should set this brush resource from code behind. And unfortunately code is not good readable.

```
// Initializing code
// And as mentioned in comments code for restore color
DrawingBrush myBrush = ( Application.Current.Resources["Disp_Origin"] as DrawingBrush ).Clone();
testButton.Background = myBrush;

// On hover or on focus code
DrawingBrush settedBrush = testButton.Background as DrawingBrush;
( ( System.Windows.Media.GeometryDrawing )( ( ( System.Windows.Media.DrawingGroup )
   ( settedBrush.Drawing ) ).Children[0] ) ).Pen.Brush = new SolidColorBrush( Colors.Red );
```

**Update**

As mentioned in comments, it needed to restore brush when the control is not focused or covered.

Comment: So, this code, clone the resource into the background of a button to handle latter, right?

The OnFocus code could be used in any control which I want? (and could be focused, of course)

Comment: Yes it is. Also you can store setted control brushes in window class private variables, and can update it whenever you want.

Comment: Looking sooooo good, I'm going to delay the test of this a little, but I want to try asap, because this could save me a lot of so much time.
Thank you.

Comment: The solution povided need some adjustments, because the color modified never come back to the original color if the code is set in the On Hover method.
It's needed another method to restore the original  DrawingBrush.

Comment: This is the extra method I'm using.

private void RestoreBrush(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawingBrush Disp_Origin_Brush = (Application.Current.Resources["Disp_Origin"] as DrawingBrush).Clone();
            Disp_Origin.Fill = Disp_Origin_Brush;

        }

Comment: Thanks, I've added this into answer.